# MySQL query not returning the desired results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the query below which queries the following two tables:

### Users

```
id | gender | interested_men | interested_wmen | name | dob      | email            | account | photoURL | timestamp
 8 | 1      |0               |1                |Jamie |1987-07-04|jampez77@gmail.com| 1       | https://.|2015-11-16 17:47:33
 9 | 0      |1               |1                |Jamima|1987-07-04|jampez87@gmail.com| 1       | https://.| 2015-11-17 14:51:38
```

### Locations

```
id | uid | lat         | lng         | timestamp
8  | 9   | 53.47213437 | -2.06999151 | 2015-11-17 15:05:37
7  | 8   | 53.47213437 | -2.06999151 | 2015-11-16 17:47:33
```

Here is the query, I'd expect it to return the details for the user called Jamima but I don't get any results. I can't see anything wrong with the syntax so i'm not sure.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
l.uid , 
u.account , 
(
    3959 * acos
    ( 
        cos( 
            radians(53.47213437) 
        ) * 
        cos( 
            radians( lat) 
        ) * 
        cos( 
            radians( lng) - radians(-2.06999151) 
        ) + 
        sin( 
            radians(53.47213437) 
        ) * 
        sin( 
            radians( lat )
        ) 
    ) 
) distance, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age 
FROM locations l 
INNER JOIN users u ON l.uid = u.id 
WHERE uid != 8 
AND gender = 0 
AND account = 1 
HAVING distance <= 200 
AND age >= 23 
AND age <= 33 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

I've noticed that if I remove the gender and account parts of the where clause i get the correct results through. even if though they match the where clause

Comment: WHERE l.uid != 8 AND u.gender = 0 AND u.account = 1 HAVING distance <= 200 AND age >= 23 AND age <= 33 ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: @user4621032 Thanks for the reply, that still produces no results though

Comment: I know that mysql is strange but using `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` make no sense, and this is your query with your data [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11902/4) it return the used id of Jamina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the datatypes in MySQL. For some reason the fact I had gender and account set to ENUM created the issue. I simply changed the to INT and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

`AND gender = 0` is in your query while the table has the value of 1 set for both people

Comment: Sorry that's a typo i'll put the correct values in now